# WP7 live tile and push notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I am trying to follow Andrea Boschin's example on how to deliver custom tile, blog post available here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Part-7-Understanding-Push-Notifications.aspx

Now his solution works perfectly, but I would love to change it to a Push notification program ( so not running inside the service ), and somehow when I try this, my tile doesn't get updated.

Anyone tried this?
Anyone care to help set this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you want functionality which is new in "Mango", that of using a background agent to update the tile.

Have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948(v=VS.92).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=VS.92).aspx

Please note that this functionality has only just been announced, is still in beta and won't be available on phone until later this year. If you have working functionality with the Push Notification services I'd recommend sticking wiht that for now and then adding this, new, exrta feature when it becomes available.

Comment: Hey Matt, yeah I've read that and indeed for my scenario I think I'll should wait until everyone is up and running Mango